# backbone: issue an ajax call before resetting a collection

Tags: ajax, collections, asynchronous, backbone.js

Right now I have a collection that fetches value, and after that every view attached to the reset event get rendered again

the problem is that I also have to issue another query to fetch the total number of records retrieved, and only after that ajax call is completed the reset event should be triggered

is more clear with a bit of code:

```
fetch: function() {
  options = { data: this.getParams() };
  this.fetch_total();
  return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
},

fetch_total: function() {
  var that = this;
  var options = { 
    url: this.url + '/count',
    data: this.getParams(),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(resp, status, xhr) {
      that.total = parseInt(resp);
      return true;
    }
  };
  return $.ajax(options);
}
```

as you can see, I have to issue a get to localhost/myentity/count to get the count of entities...

The thing is I need the collection.total varaible to be updated before refreshing the views, that means I need both request, the GET to localhost/myentity and to localhost/myentity/count, to be completed before refreshing all the views...

any idea how can I achieve it???

Comment: couldn't you just count the objects you get back from the fetch? It seems unnecessary to run two queries for this.

Comment: I should have stated the the first GET fetches just a page of items (10 records), and the count fetches the total number of records (could be hundreds), I'm using it to calculate how many pages to display, and to show a message like "displaying 21-30 of 355"... you get the idea

Answer (score 2):

If your $ of choice is jQuery>1.5, you could take advantage of the [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to manually trigger a reset event when both calls have completed. Similar to your answer, but a bit more readable and without chaining the calls:

```
fetch: function() {
  options = {silent: true, data: this.getParams()};
  var _this = this;
  var dfd_total = this.fetch_total();
  var dfd_fetch = Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);

  return  $.when(dfd_total, dfd_fetch).then(function() {
        _this.trigger('reset', _this);
  })
},

fetch_total: function() {
    // what you have in your question
}
```

And a Fiddle simulating these calls http://jsfiddle.net/rkzLn/

Of course, returning the results and the total in one fetch may be more efficient, but I guess that's not an option.

Comment: I was actually using zepto for $, but I REALLY like this deferred object stuff!!! I just wonder how does jquery knows that the functions completed, the callbacks aren't firing anything at all... ?????

Comment: @opensas The Ajax calls in jQuery are wired to return promises, dfd_total and dfd_fetch here, which you can combine ($.when here) and apply a callback when all have resolved (.then) I encourage you to read more about the Deferred object, it's really a nifty piece of code. A very good tutorial http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/

Comment: oh, and another benefit, besides the clean code, is that both queries are running in parallel, in my solution, I'm serializing two asynchronous requests, fetch_total runs AFTER the normal fetch has completed...

Comment: @opensas That's what I meant by "without chaining the calls" :)

Answer (score 1):

I think @nikoshr's answer is a good one so that you don't have to modify your API. If you think that you want to lessen your calls to the server, then consider returning an object from that endpoint that has paging information.

```
{
  count: 1243,
  page: 3,
  per_page: 10,
  results: [
    ...
  ]
}
```

and then overriding the collection's parse functionality

```
parse: function(res) {
  this.count = res.count;
  this.page = res.page;
  this.per_page = res.per_page;
  // return the collection
  return res.results;
}
```

**RESOURCES**

- http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse

Comment: sure, that's a pretty good advice, but modifying the web service is not an option...

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to do it. What I did was to silently fire the fetch call, without triggering the 'reset' event

There, from the callback, I issue the fetch of the total (GET to localhost/myentity/count)

and from the total callback, I finally trigge the reset event

in code is something like this:

```
fetch: function() {
  var that = this;
  options = {
    // will manually trigger reset event after fetching the total
    silent: true,       
    data: this.getParams(),
    success: function(collection, resp) {
      that.fetch_total();
    } 
  };
  return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
},

fetch_total: function() {
  var that = this;
  var options = { 
    url: this.url + '/count',
    data: this.getParams(),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(resp, status, xhr) {
      that.total = parseInt(resp);
      // manually trigger reset after fetching total
      that.trigger('reset', that);    
      return true;
    }
  };
  return $.ajax(options);
}
```

This is my first attempt, I wonder if there's an easier way